# Possible to do `docker exec CONTAINER NAME -c "command"?

Tags: docker

NOTE: I'm a Docker n00b and only use it for building docs. I don't know docker-fu and am NOT a programmer, so I need things spelled out clearly :)

### Issue

Each time I want to open bash for a Docker container I need to find out the container ID with:

```
$ docker ps
```

Then I have to plug the ID into a command such as:

```
$ docker exec <container> bash -c "command1 ; command2 ; command3"
```

### What I'm looking for

A way to use the static docker container name instead of the changing docker ID

Comment: Consider `docker run --rm ... image-name command` to run a temporary container, which would avoid this step.

Answer (score 0):

When running your container, give it an useful name:

```
docker run --name mystuff [...]
```

Then you can exec bash in this way:

```
docker exec mystuff bash -c "command1 ; command2 ; command3"
```